# How can I programmatically create a Google Cloud Function using the Go API client

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

There is a Go package for interacting with the Cloud Functions API ([google.golang.org/api/cloudfunctions/v1](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/api/cloudfunctions/v1)) but I can't figure out how to use it to create new functions. I'm getting 404 and 403 errors when attempting to upload to the signed URL for the Cloud Storage bucket.

Does anyone know how to use this package to deploy Cloud Functions?

Comment: Please, provide the code, the solutions you already tried. I can only copy and paste the documentation for your general question.

Answer (score 4):

I have encountered a similar issue when using  google.golang.org/api/cloudfunctions/v1, 
the first problem with 403 error I had, was due to using auth client
with presigned Generate Upload  URL, using bare http client helped

```
httpClient := http.DefaultClient
data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(reader)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
request, err := http.NewRequest("PUT", uploadURL, bytes.NewReader(data))
if err != nil {
    return err
}
request.Header.Set("content-type", "application/zip")
request.Header.Set("x-goog-content-length-range", "0,104857600")
request.Header.Set("Content-Length", fmt.Sprintf("%d", len(data)))
response, err := httpClient.Do(request)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
```

Another issue I saw with 404 was when I was using location as region as opposed to the fully qualified name presented in the below snippet

```
var location =  'projects/${projectID}/locations/${region}'  
projectService := cloudfunctions.NewProjectsLocationsFunctionsService(ctxClient.service)
createCall := projectService.Create(location, request.CloudFunction)
createCall.Context(ctxClient.Context())
return createCall.Do()
h
```

You can also check golang cloud functions google.golang.org/api/cloudfunctions/v1  API usage in this project:

[Cloud function service](https://github.com/viant/endly/blob/master/system/cloud/gcp/cloudfunctions/service.go)